# Do I kneed to import libraries for different files?

Tags: java, file, class, import, package

Say I have two files:

```java
// File Main.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       // Scanner stuff here...
       Food.fries();
   }
}
```

```java
// File Food.java
public class Food {
    public static void fries() {
        System.out.println("Some fries...")
        // Can I do Scanner stuff here without importing?
    }
}
```

I know that if classes are in the same file, I don't need to import for each class. Now, if I wanted to do operations with Scanner in class Food (separate file), do I need to import Scanner again?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?  There is no risk in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the Scanner class again to be able to use it inside `Food` class.
But, what I recommend it's you make `sc` variable as static and global **(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);)**
So, in your main class you will have to create the variable like:

```
public class Main {

   public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Scanner stuff here...
       Food.fries();
   }
}
```

And inside your Food class:

```
public static void fries() {
    System.out.println("Some fries...Give me a number:");
    Main.sc.nextInt();
}
```

> Those examples work if you have the files in the same package.

Now, you have to be careful here, Because if you have your Main class in another java package (or folder), then, you will have to import the Main class or you can use a static import. You can use that to avoid the use of the syntax **Classname.your_static_method()**. For example, your Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static yourpackagename.Food.fries;

public class Main {

   public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Scanner stuff here...
       fries();
   }
}
```

> As you can see now, I used a static import to use the `fries()` method which you have in the another class. So inside the main, you can call the method with the simple name, and not using the syntax **Classname.static_method()**

And inside Food class, you can do the same with Scanner object `(sc)`:

```
import static yourpackagename.Main.sc;

public class Food {
        public static void fries() {
            System.out.println("Some fries...Give me a number:")
            sc.nextInt();
        }
}
```

> Those examples work for files in the same package or in separate ones. You only have to do the import correctly.

Now, if you don't want to use a static import and the files or classes are in separate packages, you will have to import the class as always and use the syntax: **Classname.static_methodorvariable()**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import thepackgename.Food;

public class Main {

   public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Scanner stuff here...
       Food.fries();
   }
}
```

Food class:

```
import thepackagename.Main;

public class Food {
        public static void fries() {
            System.out.println("Some fries...Give me a number:")
            Main.sc.nextInt();
        }
}
```